# ETF portfolio for indian retiree

Tags: india, etf, retirement

I am a recent retiree and do not get a pension. I have all my savings in my bank account some of which I want to invest in an all ETF portfolio over a period of time using SIP. What are some good options for me? There aren't any good articles/blogs on the internet for Indian investors, although I could find many good articles for American investors. I hold a demat account in India and want to invest in the Indian market.